# "Cannot set session ID after the session has started" when generating csrf token within Behat test

Tags: symfony, session, behat, csrf-protection

I'm trying to test that a user with the wrong permissions sees the correct response when visting a page that has a csrf token in the path.

I've added a Behat context step to create a csrf token using the 'security.csrf.token_manager', however then visit the page with this token in the path, I get a "Cannot set session ID after the session has started" 500 error.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong, or how I work around this, please?

```
/**
 * @When /^I go to the application admin archive page for "(?P<status>[^"]*)" application (?P<number>\d+) with a valid token$/
 *
 * @param string $status
 * @param int    $number
 */
public function iGoToTheApplicationAdminArchivePageForApplicationWithAValidToken($status, $number)
{
    $tokenManager = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
    $token        = $tokenManager->getToken(ApplicationAdminController::CSRF_ARCHIVE);
    var_dump($token);

    $this->visitAdminPage('archive', $status, $number, ['token' => $token]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error message you get seems to be a result of a [bug in symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13450). Try to apply maryo's suggestion about extending MockFileSessionStorage class and checking if the id is empty before attempting to set it like this:

```
public function setId($id)
{
    if ($this->id !== $id) {
        parent::setId($id);
    }
}
```

You can then use this fixed class in your functional test by doing something like this after creating the client:

```
$client->getContainer()->set('session', new Session(new FixedMockFileSessionStorageHelper()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I still got this error at this moment. I fixed this issue by checking your file config of env at

```
app/config/config_test.yml
```

I found this configuration under **framework** section

```
framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

All what you have to do just remove this line **test: ~**
to be as below:

```
framework:
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        collect: false
```

Then clear the cache by

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=test --no-debug
```

Refresh and Enjoy ;)